# VOC conversion question

Tags: organic-chemistry, chemical-engineering

I'm trying to find out if a particular paint is considered low VOC. The only piece of data I have available is that the VOC content is $\pu{10 \mu mol / m^3}$. What does that equal in $\pu{g/L}$ of paint?

Comment: I just edited, check if actual meaning of your question is preserved..

Answer (score 2):

[VOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_organic_compound) stands for volatile organic compounds, in this context as mass concentration of vapours in the air.

These 2 mentioned quantities ( concentration in air and the paint ) are very indirectly related via volatility of paint components.

So the same VOC value may belong to huge range of g/L in the paint.